# Undefined reference to global variable during linking

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker

I am trying to compile a program which is divided into 3 modules, corresponding to 3 source files: `a.c`, `b.c`, and `z.c`. `z.c` contains the `main()` function, which calls functions in `a.c` and `b.c`. Furthermore, a function in `a.c` calls a function in `b.c`, and viceversa. Finally, there is a global variable `count` which is used by the three modules and is defined in a separate header file, `global.h`.

The code of the source files is the following:

`a.c`

```
#include "global.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

int functAb() {
    functB();
    functA();
    return 0;
}

int functA() {
    count++;
    printf("A:%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

`b.c`

```
#include "global.h"
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int functBa() {
    functA();
    functB();
    return 0;
}

int functB() {
    count++;
    printf("B:%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

`z.c`

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "global.h"

int main() {
    count = 0;
    functAb();
    functBa();
    return 0;
}
```

The header files:

`a.h`

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <stdio.h>

int functA();
int functAb();

#endif
```

`b.h`

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <stdio.h>

int functB();
int functBa();

#endif
```

`global.h`

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

extern int count;

#endif
```

And, finally, the `makefile` that reproduces my error:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -march=native -Wall -Wno-unused-result

z:  a.o b.o z.o global.h
    $(CC) -o z a.o b.o z.o $(CFLAGS)
a.o:    a.c b.h global.h
    $(CC) -c a.c $(CFLAGS)
b.o:    b.c a.h global.h
    $(CC) -c b.c $(CFLAGS)
z.o:    z.c a.h global.h
    $(CC) -c z.c $(CFLAGS)
```

With this, I can compile the objects `a.o`, `b.o`, and `z.o` fine, but, when linking with `make z`, I get `undefined reference to 'count'` in all of them:

```
z.o: In function `main':
z.c:(.text.startup+0x8): undefined reference to `count'
a.o: In function `functAb':
a.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `count'
a.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `count'
a.o: In function `functA':
a.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `count'
a.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `count'
b.o:b.c:(.text+0xd): more undefined references to `count' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I managed to reproduce the error in my actual code in this minimal example, so I guess there is a problem in the dependencies between modules, but I can't spot it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Change your `z.c` to

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "global.h"

int count; /* Definition here */
int main() {
    count = 0;
    functAb();
    functBa();
    return 0;
}
```

From `global.h`, all your files inherit the **declaration** of variable `count` but the **definition** is missing from all files.

You must add the definition to one of the file as `int count = some_value;`

Comment: Can "int count" be inside the main function?

Comment: @Taozi No, it will make the `count` a local variable. We need a global definition.

Comment: In my case, when I compile inside a Linux distro I have no issues at all, but when I try to compile the same program with cygwin, I get this error. I found that indeed my variables are declared inside a function and that maybe is the root cause of my headaches, but why does it Linux compile without complain?

Answer (score 14):

You have *declared* count, not *defined* it.

`extern` is a part of declaration, not a definition.

To be explicit, `extern` is a storage-class specifier and used at declaration.

You need to *define* `int count` somewhere in your source files.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add `int count;` to your z.c file.
This because of declaring a variable in header file as `extern` tells to the compiler that the variable will be declared in another file, but the variable is not declared yet and will be resolved b linker.

Then you need to declare the variable somewhere.

Comment: yep, it's diabolical. Sorry to all the beginners :)